# Why Is This FMDB Enqueue Block Not Executing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I've created this method in my iOS to call to `FMDatabaseQueue`:

```
-(void) enqueueSelectStatement:(NSString*)selectStatement withArguments:(NSArray*)args {
            
    NSLog(@"Checkpoint 1");
            
            
    [self.dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
                   
        FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery:selectStatement withArgumentsInArray:args];
                    
        NSLog(@"Checkpoint 2");

    }];
            
                
    NSLog(@"Checkpoint 3");
           
}
```

When I call this method with:

> NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";
>
> [self enqueueSelectStatement:query withArguments:@[1]];

I get `Checkpoint 1` in my terminal output, but nothing else. The app does not crash and continues to run, but the method/block apparently dies after `Checkpoint 1`

Is the method just stopping, and if so, why?

Comment: please provide the crash log.

Comment: "but apparently dies after Checkpoint 1". Is it printing anything to the log ?

Comment: You state *"The app does not crash"* and *"but apparently dies"*. Those two statements contradict each other. Does it crash or not?

Comment: Edited : The app does not crash, but the method apparently dies

Comment: Methods don't die. The method can get stuck or the app crashes but a method doesn't just die. Use the debugger and step into the code and see what happens.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after checkpoint 1, and then print out a stack trace.  I bet you either have another thread blocking on a statement… or maybe an open result set.